# how to change path of multi files c#

Tags: c#, windows, filepath

In this code im getting the filename from the path the user choose and i want to edit the text file and save it to text but i want it to be `(filename+new).txt`  my code is getting `filename.txtnew` :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

    string[] fileArray = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
    foreach (string filename in fileArray)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        //string path = @"C:\Users\rabih\Desktop\uni\IR\textNoStopWords"+".txt ";
        string path = filename + "new";
        richTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
        string st = richTextBox1.Text;
        string[] split = st.Split(' ');
        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            if (!Stopwords.Contains(s.ToLower()))
            {
                //richTextBox2.Text += s + " ";
            }
        }
        richTextBox2.Text += path + " \n";
        using (File.Create(path)) ;
        richTextBox2.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can think of using `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to get just file name without extension and then add "New" to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the fileName by `.` and construct the new `FileName`, like the following code:

```
private static string GetNewFileName(string oldFileName)
{
    string[] splitedFileName = oldFileName.Split('.');

    return string.Concat(splitedFileName[0], "new.", splitedFileName[1]);
}
```

Call the `GetNewFileName` in your code :

```
string newFileName = GetNewFileName(filename);
```

I hope that will help you fix the issue.